# How to get the raw request with dio package on flutter

Tags: flutter, post, dio

Is there any way to get the 'raw' part of the request like on this website: https://reqbin.com ?
I have been trying for hours to figure out why my request is perfectly fine on curl and this website and still have problems in android studio with [dio package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio).
I could figure out in one instant if only I could get the raw output of the request sent by dio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured out a simple way just by using devtool and check network, then click on the POST method.

To install devtools follow [these instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/cli)